# I am writing a powershell script to get all users whose password expire within 14 days, but it is grabbing from more than 14 days. Why?

Tags: powershell

```
Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False} –Properties "DisplayName", "samaccountname", "PasswordNeverExpires", "PasswordLastSet", "PasswordExpired", "GivenName", "SurName", "EmailAddress", "lastlogon", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" | Select-Object -Property "Displayname", "samaccountname", "PasswordNeverExpires", "PasswordLastSet", "PasswordExpired", "GivenName", "SurName", "EmailAddress", "LastLogon", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed",@{Name="ExpiryDate";Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed").ToShortDateString()}} | Where {($_.ExpiryDate -le $date.adddays(14).ToShortDateString()) -and ($_.ExpiryDate -ge $date.adddays(0).ToShortDateString())}
```

---

Here is a screenshot that it is outputting for the expiration dates. It shouldn't grab past 3/03/22, but I am seeing up to March 14th. I am not sure why the Where constraints aren't properly being applied.

[image: Output for testing]

```
`Get-ADUser 
-filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False} 
–Properties "DisplayName", "samaccountname", "PasswordNeverExpires", "PasswordLastSet", "PasswordExpired", "GivenName", "SurName", "EmailAddress", "lastlogon", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" 
| Select-Object -Property "Displayname", "samaccountname", "PasswordNeverExpires", "PasswordLastSet", "PasswordExpired", "GivenName", "SurName", "EmailAddress", "LastLogon", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed",
@{Name="ExpiryDate";
Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}} 
| Where {($_.ExpiryDate -le $date.adddays(14)) 
-and ($_.ExpiryDate -ge $date.adddays(0))}`
```

Following Theo's suggestion of not using the String comparison the command works as intended. Thank you very much Theo.

Comment: Where is `$date` defined?

Comment: Always compare datetime objects to datetime objects. You are stringifying the dates and therefore are comparing **strings**. Also, your code would improve if you do not try to slam it all in one line.

Comment: $date is simply get-date in a variable

Comment: I agree I should break it up into multiple lines.

Comment: The reason for the conversion to strings it that when I pull the expiry date from the ADUser it comes in a FileTime format using the msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed and I wasn't sure how to deal with it at the time.

Comment: If `$date` is the current timestamp, then you probably want Where-Object {$_.ExpiryDate -ge $date.adddays(-14)}. This would compare the expiration date to 14 days ago.

Comment: i agree with everyone above. I have never been a huge fan of everything in one line but I am by far the least experienced of all the comments above.
Break it up, and compare date to date.

Comment: You should be able to filter by date in your filter.

Comment: Do one of you guys want to post it as an answer. Following Theo's advice about not using string I was able to get it to work perfectly. I am really new to Powershell, so I am not super familiar with all of the different ways I can filter and I was unaware of Where-Object as well. It's really only a one liner because I wasn't sure how to break it up without breaking it.

Comment: Well... you have managed to solve it with the advice given in comments, so I invite you to post the answer yourself. Maybe a few more tips: [1] You don't have to specify SamAccountName, GivenName or SurName in the `-Properties` parameter as these are returned always by default. [2] The `-Filter` should actually be a string, not a scriptblock [3] The code could use some indentation to make it better readable. [4] Set the reference date to midnight with `$date.adddays(14).Date`, so it is not dependant of the time you run this script. All-in-all, well done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the comments under my post I was able to correct this query and get it working properly.

The reason for the conversion to strings it that when I pulled the expiry date from the ADUser it comes in a FileTime format using the msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed and I wasn't sure how to deal with it at the time, so I had converted it to a DateTime. Then to a String thinking it would be easier to deal with. This was not the case as pointed out by Theo.

I also went ahead and made my query not all on one line.

```
Get-ADUser -filter {Enabled -eq $True -and PasswordNeverExpires -eq $False -and samaccountname -notlike 'iss*'}`
 –Properties "DisplayName", "samaccountname", "PasswordNeverExpires", "PasswordLastSet", "PasswordExpired", "GivenName", `
 "SurName", "EmailAddress", "lastlogon", "Department", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed" `
 | Select-Object -Property "Displayname", "samaccountname", "PasswordNeverExpires", "PasswordLastSet", "PasswordExpired", "GivenName", "SurName", `
 "EmailAddress", "LastLogon", "Department", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed",@{Name="ExpiryDate";`
 Expression={[datetime]::FromFileTime($_."msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed")}} `//this was the location of the initial conversion to String that led me to think to the conversion had to take place
 | Where {($_.ExpiryDate -le $date.adddays(14)) -and ($_.ExpiryDate -ge $date.adddays(0))} `
```

Although it still doesn't translate well here.